# Can't write data to a file. All System.IO methods doesn't work. Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, system.io.file

I am making a simple `iOS` app using a `Xamarin.Forms`. I use `SQLite` through `Mono.Data.Sqlite library`. I need to insert data in database through `INSERT` command and writing data to a text file. All files (text files, .db-file, images) I have stored to Resources directory in iOS project.
When I try to writing data into a text file or `INSERT` into my database the program does nothing. Data isn't inserted/written. And no exception was thrown. For example:

```
public partial class SomePage : ContentPage
{
    public SomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("some_file.txt"))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("some data");
        }
    }
}
```

The data wasn't written and the file is still empty.

I use macOS Catalina 10.15.4 and Visual Studio for Mac 8.6.1

I have searched for this problem but nothing can solve this problem. Wait for your answers! Thanks!

Comment: To isolate the problem, I suggest adding some code that *reads* the file. Then edit the file manually and see if your program picks up he changes. That way you can tell if the program is looking in the same place (path) that you are expecting.

Comment: your app bundle is signed and therefor is read-only at runtime.  Please read the docs on file handling - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files

Comment: @Jason so I need to use file as Embedded Resource?

Comment: @JohnWu Yes, I have changed data in file by file explorer and program reads it correctly.

Comment: if you want to write to a file (or db) it has to be placed in a writable folder - see the docs.  If you are including an existing db in your app, you will need to copy it from Resources or Assets at app startup to a writable folder.

Comment: @Jason In my settings Resource folder is a writeable folder.

Comment: I already told you that **your app bundle is signed and therefor is read-only at runtime**

Comment: @Jason sorry my friend, you know how to change it to read and write at runtime?

Comment: I've already explained this to you.  There are also numerous docs (like the one I already linked to), posts, and samples that demonstrate file handling in Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Jason, he showed me right way :) So the solution is to copy a files that attached in *Resources* at app startup to a *writeable* folder, like a **Documents** folder in iOS Application Sandbox. So we can use a **Environment** class to reach this folder.

```
public partial class SomePage : ContentPage
{
    public SomePage()
    {
        string filepath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "some_file.txt");
        File.Copy("some_file.txt", filepath); // From Resource folder to Documents
        File.WriteAllText(filepath, "Some text");
    }
}
```